# Can successfully deploy app to CE 7 device over TCP but can't start debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a .NET application on a Radwag PUE71 terminal running Windows CE 7 Toradex.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and connecting to the device over TCP.

I can successfully connect to the terminal from VS and deploy the application however whenever I try to start debugging I get an error "Unable to start debugging".

If any more details are required I will do my best to provide.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's working with WCE 6.0 but not for WCE 7.0. Same device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved this quite a while ago.

There is a custom SDK for Toradex which needs to be installed.

Visit the following page:
http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/windows-ce/development-tools#Installation_of_Toradex_SDKs_using_VS2008

Follow the instructions exactly.